# url rewriting on localhost

Tags: apache, url-rewriting, localhost

I have WAMP installed on my local machine. I have configured the apache module for rewrite_mod and trying a very basic example to redirect

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^alice.html$ bob.html
```

As per this rule when I hit alice.html I should be viewing bob.html content. But, I think the url rewriting is not effective.

I have /test folder placed under www and alice.html and bob.html both are place inside the test folder.

Any advice to resolve this.

Thanks

This is resolved.

Comment: RewriteLog "C:\rewritelog.log"
RewriteLogLevel 5 ........added this directive in end of file and now facing internal server error...any idea.........

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable the mod_rewrite module for Apache ? You need to enable this module for using rewrite directives. Don't forget to restart Apache after enabling the module.