# I Cannot get rewriterule to work

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, localhost, url-rewrite-module

I'm using VertrigoServ 2.27 on my laptop (localhost:8080).

Rewrite module is enabled and i tested it with alice.html and bob.html example
(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6944521/url-rewriting-on-localhost)
and it works with .htacces inside www-subfolder. And I also put rubbish text inside .htaccess and
I got error from Apcheserver so rewrite mod is running and I cab use rules.

```
here is the rule: (inside /www/folder1/.htaccess)
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine  On
RewriteRule /(.*) /index.php?disp=$1 [QSA,L]
```

So when I put this url into browser my index page loaded ok. 
http://localhost:8080/folder1/index.php

And the problem is here: When I request login via index.page(login page) and send url to localhost 
server by cliking send-button 
the url changed localhost:8080/login, it should be localhost:8080/folder1/login

- how I can keep subfolder name in url?

and I want convert urls like this: www.best-food-of-the-usa.com/index.php?operation=top&state=arizona&
city=mesa&limit=10

to  like this: www.best-food-of-the-usa.com/arizona/mesa/top10.html

Any help is appreciated. Thanks
\Jose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RewriteRule` is behaving as the docs say.

From [RewriteRule Directive <sup>Apache Docs</sup>](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)

> What is matched?
>
> In VirtualHost context, The Pattern will initially be matched against the part of the URL after the hostname and port, and before the query string (e.g. "/app1/index.html").
>
> In Directory and htaccess context, the Pattern will initially be matched against the filesystem path, after removing the prefix that lead the server to the current RewriteRule (e.g. "app1/index.html" or "index.html" depending on where the directives are defined).
>
> If you wish to match against the hostname, port, or query string, use a RewriteCond with the %{HTTP_HOST}, %{SERVER_PORT}, or %{QUERY_STRING} variables respectively.

So, when in `Directory and htaccess` context the prefix `/www/folder1/` will be removed. Also remember when matching with `RewriteRule` in `Directory and htaccess` context, the pattern will never begin with `/`.

So, your `RewriteRule` Should be:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine  On
RewriteRule (.*) /index.php?disp=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thank you very much.

OK, I put rewriterule inside VirtualHost context and now it works.

That information about .htaccess was very good to know (context the prefix /www/folder1/ will be removed AND pattern will initially be matched against the filesystem path) so I don't wonder any more why my rules dont work inside htaccess.

\Jose